# Performing a view animation after adding the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

So my problem is that i want after double click on item in RecyclerView adapter to trigger the animation on ImageView. I detect the double tap in adapter, take the coordinates of the tapped area in format of `int[] location`,  call the method in Fragment passing the location.

```
public void performAnimation(int[] location) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_imageview));
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.setMargins(0, location[0], 0, location[1]);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    parentViewGroup2.addView(imageView);


    ObjectAnimator translateAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0.5f);
    translateAnim.setDuration(2000);
    translateAnim.start();
```

So the problem is that i only get to draw the image in layout, but animation wont start. I have also tryed that with TransitionManager with beginDelayedTransition, but again, nothing. Does anyone have any idea what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` receives an array of float values of which value the animation will run through, you only pass 1 `0.5f` param which is not enough. Also, the `float` here should be an absolute pixel on the screen will be translated, not an offset value.

Try this `ViewPropertyAnimator` instead:

```
imageView.animate().translationY(400).setDuration(200).start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with ViewPropertyAnimator :) I was a bit confused because of various ways and APIs to perform some sort of animation on Views. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Glad I can help, you can mark this as answered so it can help others